# How to get into function from cartesian product of two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As I know, functions are special types of relations and relations are the subsets of cartesian product between two sets. But how can a non-surjective function result from cartesian product?

Comment: Are you familiar with how a relation can be viewed a subset of a cartesian product?

Comment: What do you mean  by "result from"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what you have probably seen functions as so far. You define a function from a domain $A$ to a codomain $B$ such that you can't have anything in the domain map to more than one element in the codomain. For ex. we can define $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as the function $f(n) = n^2$.

What this means is that $f$ maps things from $\mathbb{N}$ to other things in $\mathbb{N}$ like:

$$
\begin{align}
f(1) &= 1 \\
f(2) &= 4 \\
f(3) &= 9 \\
f(4) &= 16 \\
\vdots    \\ 
f(n) &= n^2
\end{align}
$$

Now consider the cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. This is jut all ordered pairs $\left <a,b \right >$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$.

You can view the function $f$ as set of ordered pairs $\left <x,y \right >$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ where $y$ is the element in the codomain that $f$ maps $x$  to. So in the case of our example, $f$ could be the set of ordered pairs as such:

$$
f = \left \{\left < 1,1\right >, \left < 2,4\right >,\left < 3,9\right >, \left < 4,16\right >\ldots \right\}
$$

Notice this set $f$ is just a subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The function you have given in your answer is bijective. Bijective function can result from cartesian product, I don't have a problem with that. But how can one get a  non-surjective function from a cartesian product?

Comment: @Nabin The example in my answer is not a surjective function. For example, $3, 5, 6, 7, 8$ etc are in the codomain but are never mapped to. If you would like me to do another example, just give me an example of a function (ideally involving a countable set like the integers so that I can list out the elements of the function) and I will add it to my answer.

Comment: My concern was that the set f ,on its own, wasn't showing the non-surjective behaviour. But I think i now got it. Thanks.

Comment: The confusion here arises because if you encode a function $f$ simply as a set of ordered pairs, then surjectivity becomes ill-defined, since for example the set $f$ of ordered pairs considered as a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is equal to the same set $f$ of ordered pairs considered as a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$. If you want surjectivity to be a well-defined concept, you need to build the domain and codomain into the encoding of the function somehow, e.g. in this case by taking $f = (\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N},S_f)$, where $S_f$ is the set of ordered pairs in gowrath's answer.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Isn't that simplicity clarified when you say $f \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ vs $f \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @gowrath: It's not encoded in $f$ as a mathematical object in its own right. You could say "surjective onto $\mathbb{N}$" or "surjective onto $\mathbb{Z}$" to clarify things.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Those are some interesting metalogical points. I would have to respectfully disagree though. Following your reasoning one could say the normal definition of a function is not a mathematical object in its own right because you need to specify its domain and codomain. I think the definition of a function as $f : A \to B$  is no more an encapsulated object on its own right than definition of a function as $f \subseteq A \times B$ . Perhaps I'm missing your point though. I would love to hear a rebuttal; I may be completely off.

Comment: @gowrath: If you want to define the notion of "function from $A$ to $B$" as a subset of $A \times B$ (with a certain property), then it's fine to define it as a subset of $A \times B$. The problem arises if you want to define the notion of a "function", because if a function is defined to be a set of ordered pairs, then it has no well-defined codomain. According to this definition, $\{ (1,1), (2,3), (3,2) \}$ is a function; it is both a function $[3] \to [3]$ and a function $[3] \to \mathbb{R}$, and so the question "what is the codomain of $\{ (1,1), (2,3), (3,2) \}$?" has no answer.